# Can I screw down laminate floor that is coming up

Tags: flooring, laminate

Removed a kitchen wall in the middle of room, friend floated in the tongue and groove laminate and then glued down. 2 pieces are popping up, one on corner and other on side. Can I use tiny screws and wood putty? The floor is discontinued, trying to find a fix vs new floors. Thanks[image]

Comment: Floating floors shouldn't be fastened at a single point. 1. Why was laminate glued down? 2. Popping up how? In the field? At an edge? Please post photos or a better description of both the product and situation.

Comment: They cut off tongue and groove, not sure why they glued. I think the Floor is not level under neath. Will try to attach photo.

Comment: Thanks, but that photo doesn't show us anything meaningful. A clear photo of the patch area would be much better.

Comment: They had to cut the pieces to retrofit the floor with the wall gone, the problem is if you anchor it in place screw it down it will probably screw up the flooring, most laminates are designed to be free floating.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer provided, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 1):

Floating floors are normally fit around walls. Really, any flooring is. The right fix here is to work full flooring planks into the existing floor, which means disassembling some of the floor or using manufacturer-prescribed tools and techniques install planks in the middle of the floor.

In your case, without enough product, a hack fix is maybe your only option. I'd try to find some very thin plywood or synthetic sheet that you can use to bandage the filler planks to the original planks on the underside.

Otherwise, fastening the fillers down and hoping for the best is an option. If your floating floor moves around after you've eliminated the expansion joints, though, you may see opening of joints in the field.